# Unable to refill events after ClearAll in responsive calender

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to clear the events and then repopulate. But when I clear the events, it just doesn't add any new events.

```
var events = GetDayEventCount(month, year, zip, radius, categories);
        $('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar('clearAll');
        $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({                    
            allRows: false,
            events: events               
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit functionality resolved issue

```
      var events = ddt;
      $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
        events:ddt
      });
      $('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar('edit', events);
```